# Reverse a string using stack Java

Tags: java, string, data-structures, stack

The title of the question explains itself. I am trying to solve this problem however I am not successful in doing so.
**Here, is how the problem looks:**

You are given a string S, the task is to reverse the string using stack.

Example 1:

Input: S="GeeksforGeeks"
Output: skeeGrofskeeG

Your Task:
You don't need to read input or print anything. Your task is to complete the function reverse() which takes the string S as an input parameter and returns the reversed string.

Expected Time Complexity: O(N)
Expected Auxiliary Space: O(N)

**My code:**

```
class Solution {
    Stack<Character> s1=new Stack<Character>();
    Stack<Character> s2=new Stack<Character>();
    
    public String reverse(String S){
        String temp="";
        //code here
        for(int i=0;i<S.length();i++){
            s1.push(S.charAt(i));   
        }
        while(!s1.isEmpty()){
            s2.push(s1.pop());
        }
        while(!s2.isEmpty()){
            temp=temp+s2.pop();
        }
        return temp;
    }

}
```

All my testcases are failing. Help will be appreciated!

Comment: You only need one stack. Push all the characters of the original string onto the stack, then pop them off to build the reversed string one character at a time. I think your code might be reversing it twice with the two stacks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are using two stacks (`s1` and `s2`) which is unnecessary for this problem. The purpose of a stack in reversing a string is to make use of its Last In, First Out (LIFO) property. When you push characters of the string onto a stack and then pop them, they come out in reverse order. Therefore, a single stack is sufficient to achieve the desired result.

Here's how you can modify your code:

1. Push each character of the string `S` onto the stack.
2. Pop each character from the stack and append it to the result string.

This will reverse the string as each character is popped off in the reverse order of how they were pushed.

Here is the revised version of your code:

```java
class Solution {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

    public String reverse(String S){
        String result = "";

        // Push each character onto the stack
        for(int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++){
            stack.push(S.charAt(i));
        }

        // Pop each character from the stack and append to result
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            result += stack.pop();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This revised version should work correctly and pass the test cases, as it correctly implements the stack to reverse the string.

Comment: `result = stack.pop();` is O(n ^ 2), so test cases with large input will timeout. Instead, use a `new StringBuilder(S.length())` to build the result in O(n), or populate a `byte[]` and  pass it to a String constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using only one stack and StringBuilder

```
 public String reverse(String S){

    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++){
        stack.push(S.charAt(i));   
    }
    
    StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder();
    
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        reversed.append(stack.pop());
    }
    
    return reversed.toString();
}
```

Run time complexity is O(N)